# Not all Mongo fields showing up when called in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I console.log the user currently logged in from the server side I see all the fields.  When I do the same from the client side I only get the _id, and email field.  I'm pretty sure I'm subscribed correctly.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  user.subreddits = [];
  console.log(user);
  return user;
});

Meteor.publish('users', function(){
  return Meteor.users.find().fetch();
});

SinglePost = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('users');
    return {
    };
  },
deletePost: function(){
  var post_to_delete = {_id: this.props.id}
  Posts.remove(post_to_delete);
},
showMeInfo: function(){
  console.log(Meteor.user());
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <div>
      <li>
        <button onClick={this.deletePost}> Click Me!</button>                {this.props.title}: {this.props.content}
      </li>
    <p><button onClick={this.showMeInfo}> Show Me Info! </button>           </p>
    </div>
  );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of

> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are
>   published to the client.

from the doc [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users)

Update your onCreateUser like this

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){

  if (options.profile) user.profile = options.profile;
  if (user.profile == null) user.profile = {};

  user['profile'].subreddits = [];
  console.log(user);
  return user;
});
```

Comment: How do I be able to read and write to the subreddit attribute of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.users will only publish the current users profile if autopublish is removed.

Add the below publish to your server code:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
    if (!this.userId) return this.ready();
    return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

A null publish will be auto-published and auto-subscribed by the client if autopublish is removed.

Also, remember to include only those fields that are not sensitive. For, Eg. you might want to omit the password field or the services field.

Something like this:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
            profile : 1,
            emails  : 1
        }
    });
```